# ¿En qué parte de Microsoft Azure configuro el acceso ftp para Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, azure, microsoft

Instalé wordpress en nginx que está corriendo en una máquina virtual de Ubuntu (Linux (ubuntu 20.04)). Todo me funciona muy bien, el único inconveniente es al tratar de instalar cualquier plugin desde wordpress, este me pide acceso a ftp.
He intentado muchas cosas, aquí les detallo:

Instalé `vsftpd`, configuré la ruta `sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf` y metí estas líneas al archivo:

```
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
pasv_enable=YES
```

tampoco funcionó. De hecho solo puedo acceder desde el puerto 22. Es decir, sí puedo acceder desde ftp con los datos del servidor, usuario, contraseña y puerto 22, solo se accede correctamente en filezilla.
Sin embargo, cuando ingreso esos mismos datos en wordpress, me arroja ese problema:
`Fallo al conectar al servidor FTP (la ip de mi servidor)`

```
Para realizar la operación que has solicitado WordPress necesita tener acceso a tu servidor web. 
Por favor, introduce tus datos de acceso FTP para proceder. 
Si no recuerdas tus datos de acceso deberías contactar con tu proveedor de alojamiento.
```

[image: Captura ss del error]

¿Hay alguna forma de resolver este problema, un manual que me sirva o cualquier cosa que pueda solucionar esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para configurar el acceso FTP para WordPress en Microsoft Azure, deberás seguir los siguientes pasos:

Accede a tu cuenta de Microsoft Azure y selecciona la máquina virtual de Ubuntu que estás utilizando para alojar tu sitio web.

En la sección de configuración de red de la máquina virtual, asegúrate de que el puerto FTP (21) esté habilitado en la configuración de seguridad de red.

Crea un usuario FTP para WordPress y establece una contraseña para este usuario utilizando el siguiente comando en la terminal:

```
sudo useradd -d /var/www/html -s /bin/false wordpressftp
sudo passwd wordpressftp
```

Configura los permisos de los archivos y directorios de tu sitio web para que el usuario FTP tenga permiso para escribir en ellos. Puedes hacerlo utilizando los siguientes comandos en la terminal:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:wordpressftp /var/www/html
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
```

Finalmente, en la configuración de WordPress, introduce los datos de acceso FTP (usuario, contraseña, servidor y puerto) que acabas de crear en el servidor FTP.

Con estos pasos, deberías ser capaz de configurar el acceso FTP para WordPress en Microsoft Azure y solucionar el problema que estás experimentando al tratar de instalar plugins a través de WordPress. Saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio